# 1 of my PSN accounts was lost is it recoverable as well as it's DLC's?

Tags: ps3, psn

I feel like an idiot, but I had 2 PSN accounts on my PS3 which had all my online games. The other had all my money but recently I got a free DLC on my game account and my account with my money was deleted by accident. Is it possible to get that account back with all the DLCs and money?

Comment: What do you mean by 'my account... was deleted'? Do you just mean that you logged out and then accidentally removed the associated user from the system? Because that's fixable :)

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new user on your system (ps3), it is given the option to create a new account or login with a existing account to the Playstation Network.

You just need to choose the second option (login with a existing account).

Login with the email and password of that account. You will regain the "deleted" account and all of his purchases, money, DLC, trophies, etc.